# (Rails 6 specific) How to validate a date for future events only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

In rails 7 I could use the ComparisonValidator and make my life easier, but I have a project that is running rails 6.1.7.3 (to be exact). Scoured the internet but certain methods are deprecated with 10+ years old approaches and other ones require more complex workaround -- I'm curious if there's a simpler way to do this.

I'm doing a ticketmaster style project; I have a `Concerts` model, with a `date` attribute. The user can enter dates aren't in the past (and also ideally aren't today either).

I'm looking to do something similar to below basically but in a proper way that would work for Rails6. For example, `Concert.first` has `date: "2023-06-17"`; the code below doesn't work, it's just my way of showing what I'm looking for conceptually.

```
class Concert < ApplicationRecord
    
   validates :date, presence: true, comparison: {greater_than: Date.today}
    
end
```

Any step in the right direction or any thoughts in general would be immensely appreciated

EDIT: I've accepted spickermann's answer but added a small thing onto it, in my answer below. This is what I went with in my own project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [custom validation method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) in cases like these.

```
validate :date_must_be_in_the_future

private 

def date_must_be_in_the_future
  errors.add(:date, "can't be in the past") unless date.future?
end
```

Comment: Thank you spickermann! I went with this one as I only have one model I need this for, but added an addendum (thanks to a redditor who helped me out) where I add an on: :create after the 'validate :date_must_be_in_the_future' such that no record will be invalidated over time.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to a validation method it's pretty easy to implement a validator class that lets you re-use the validation for any model and attribute.

```
# app/validators/future_validator.rb
class FutureValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return if value > Date.today
    errors.add(attribute, "can't be in the past")
  end
end
```

```
class Concert < ApplicationRecord
   validates :date, presence: true, future: true
end
```

There is a also quite a [few gems that provide chronological validation methods](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness).

Comment: Thank you max! The gems are good ones as well and I appreciate the ability to extrapolate this validation to other models.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken spickermann's answer and added an addendum to it, inspired by a friend on another site, who recommended I added an on: :create condition, to ensure the database's concerts wouldn't be invalid over time (assuming somebody relaunched their own instance of this project or the database had to be reset and re-seeded). What I'm left with is this:

```
validate :date_must_be_in_the_future, on: :create

private 

def date_must_be_in_the_future
  errors.add(:date, "can't be in the past") unless date.future?
end
```